# Find One and Update in Mongoose with reference to other models is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a model named **OrderModel** and it has reference to other models as well

```
const orderSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  address: { type: addressSchema, required: false },
  items: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Items' }],
  date: { type: Date, default: moment(new Date()) },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' },
  is_completed: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false },
  is_canceled: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false }
});
```

and when I want to update this model, using PATCH, it is giving me an error,

```
CastError: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "["5f0c9493f833e23a0028bd31,5f0c9429f833e23a0028bd2f"]" at path "items"
```

Here is how I do it in my code,

```
    router.patch('/order', (req, res) => {
      const query = { _id: req.body._id };
      const _token = req.headers.authorization;
      let data = req.body;
      jwt.verify(_token, process.env.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, (err, decoded) => {
         console.log(query);
         if (err) {
            res.json({ message: 'Token Invalid'.err });
         } else {
            OrderModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, data, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {
                console.log(doc,query);
                if (doc) {
                    return res.json({ message: 'Succesfully saved', data: doc });
                }
                return res.json({ message: `No order found for id ${req.body._id}` });
            });
          }
       })
    })
```

i have two items as an Array, sent from frontend

```
{
  "_id": "5f8f1b7b29cbed4a8495d646",
  "items":"5f0c9493f833e23a0028bd31,5f0c9429f833e23a0028bd2f",
  "user":"5f06060110b7881ac0244005",
  "address":{
     "line_1": "Address line 1",
     "line_2": "Address line 1",
     "city": "Los Angeles",
     "state": "California",
     "pin": "90210"
  },
  "is_completed": false,
  "is_canceled": false
}
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I dont know whether its a typo but frontend should send `["5f0c9493f833e23a0028bd31","5f0c9429f833e23a0028bd2f"]`

Comment: its a typo. corrected it.

Comment: what is your req.body exactly?

Comment: updated the question with request body

Comment: @BiswaBhusan like you said the typo fixed the issue. Thanks, mate

Comment: "items": ["5f0c9493f833e23a0028bd31" , "5f0c9429f833e23a0028bd2f"]

Comment: Ah! Nice Good Luck